# Asking about future life or job

Tags: verbs, colloquial-language

To ask a child or a teen about their future job, should one ask: "What would you like to be later?" or "What would you like to do later?"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The idiom, even a cliché, is

> What do you want to be when you grow up?

…unless they're about to actually leave school to find work, in which case the word 'career' pops up a lot, whether or not they're actually likely to to have one to look forward to.

Variations on "What would you like to do later?" sounds like you're asking if they want to go to the cinema after dinner, rather than prepare for their entire working life.

Comment: I agree that "later" at the end of the sentence does imply "later [today]", but I think it would be fine to also ask explicitly _"What would you like to do later **in life**?"_, although "later in life" does slightly imply old age

Comment: Yeah, "What do you want to do later?" is *exactly* what you ask someone about after dinner, the game is over, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the teens age, but an older teen could already have started university or starting to narrow down their path by selecting courses in highschool (or equivalent), so "**What career are you pursuing?"**, might be a valid question if they seem to have their minds set on something. Or **"What do you want to do after you graduate?"**